# arm-neon conversion between uint32x2x2_t and int32x4_t

Tags: assembly, arm, intrinsics, neon

I'm trying to implement a drop in neon equivalent for `_mm_mul_epu32` for some code that is using [sse2neon](https://github.com/jratcliff63367/sse2neon), with `_mm_mul_epu32` being the only call the code uses that [sse2neon](https://github.com/jratcliff63367/sse2neon) doesn't have an equivalent for.

```
FORCE_INLINE __m128i _mm_mul_epu32(__m128i a, __m128i b)
{
    // shuffle: 0, 1, 2, 3 -> 0, 2, 1, 3 */
    __m128i const a_shuf = (int32x4_t)(vzip_u32(vget_low_u32(vreinterpretq_u32_m128i(a)), vget_high_u32(vreinterpretq_u32_m128i(a))));
    __m128i const b_shuf = (int32x4_t)(vzip_u32(vget_low_u32(vreinterpretq_u32_m128i(b)), vget_high_u32(vreinterpretq_u32_m128i(b))));

    // Multiply low word (32 bit) against low word (24 bit) and high word (32 bit) against high word (32 bit).
    // Pack both results (64 bit) into 128 bit register and return result.
    return vreinterpretq_m128i_u64(vmull_u32(vget_low_u32(vreinterpretq_u32_m128i(a_shuf)), vget_low_u32(vreinterpretq_u32_m128i(b_shuf))));
}
```

I've got something that seems to basically be equivalent - however I'm unsure what the correct way to cast the result of `vzip_u32` (which is `uint32x2x2_t`) to what the other functions expect `int32x4_t`.

For most other neon conversions there are conversion functions e.g. `vreinterpretq_u32_s32` but I can't find one for this.

I can force the cast to compile and if I do the results are correct (passes my test vectors), however I don't like this, and am wondering if there is a more correct way to handle things.

What is the correct way to convert between these types, is there one? Or is there some better way to do the shuffle such that I can avoid the conversion altogether?

Godbolt examples with some forced casting:
https://godbolt.org/z/gRDpRs
https://godbolt.org/z/H-3fOt

Comment: First of all, double-check that you actually *need* the high-half results; some SSE2 code emulates SSE4.1  `_mm_mullo_epi32` in terms of SSE2 `_mm_mul_epu32`.  Also, AArch64 doesn't need any shuffle instructions to do packed 32x32 -> 64 multiply. https://godbolt.org/z/kiyoOi shows GCC auto-vectorizing a widening 32x32 -> 64-bit `dst[i] = a[i] * (uint64_t)b[i]` with `umull   v2.2d, v0.2s, v1.2s` and `umull2  v0.2d, v0.4s, v1.4s`.  (Note that `umull2` reads the high half of the src vector for you and isn't needed on ARM32 NEON because you just read the upper `d` reg that aliases that `q` reg)

Comment: In terms of intrinsics, IDK how to wrestle the compiler into doing something useful, but I'd highly recommend checking the surrounding SSE code to see if it shuffles the multiply results around in a way that you can optimize away instead of faithfully emulating everything.

Comment: Anyway, presumably there's a cast / reinterpret intrinsic. 
 (BTW, https://godbolt.org/z/NwSBfm is ARM32 auto-vectorization.)

Comment: The code in question does make use of the high half results, its fblamka from argon2 algorithm.

SSE2:

`static BLAKE2_INLINE __m128i fBlaMka_SSE2(__m128i x, __m128i y) { const __m128i z = _mm_mul_epu32(x, y); return _mm_add_epi64(_mm_add_epi64(x, y), _mm_add_epi64(z, z)); }`



Reference:
`static BLAKE2_INLINE uint64_t fBlaMka(uint64_t x, uint64_t y) { const uint64_t m = UINT64_C(0xFFFFFFFF); const uint64_t xy = (x & m) * (y & m);
    return x + y + 2 * xy; }`